# Converting Movie Box Office to Numbers

Tags: r, movies

I have a data frame in R with box office number listed like $121.5M and $0.014M and I'd like to convert them to straight numbers. I'm thinking of striping the $ and M and then using basic multiplication. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this either by matching the non-numeric elements (`[^0-9.]*`) and replace it by `''`

```
 as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]*", '', "$121.5M"))
 #[1] 121.5
```

Or by specifically matching the `$` and `M` (`[$M]`) and replace it with `''`

```
 as.numeric(gsub("[$M]", '',"$121.5M"))
 #[1] 121.5
```

#### Update

If you have a vector like below

```
v1 <- c("$1.21M", "$0.5B", "$100K", "$1T", "$0.9P", "$1.5K")
```

Create another vector with the numbers and set the names with the corresponding abbrevations

```
v2 <- setNames(c(1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12, 1e15), c('K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P'))
```

Use that as index to replace the abbrevation and multiply it with the numeric part of the vector.

```
 as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]*", '',v1))* v2[sub('[^A-Z]*', '', v1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This removes the `$` and translates `K` and `M` to `e3` and `e6`.  There is an example very similar to this in the gsubfn vignette.

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- c("$1.21M", "$100K")  # input

ch <- gsubfn("[KM$]", list(K = "e3", M = "e6", "$" = ""), x)
as.numeric(ch)
## [1] 1210000  100000
```

The `as.numeric` line can be omitted if you don't need to convert it to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

The function `extract_numeric` from the `tidyr` package strips all non-numeric characters from a string and returns a number.  With your example:

```
library(tidyr)
dat <- data.frame(revenue = c("$121.5M", "$0.014M"))
dat$revenue2 <- extract_numeric(dat$revenue)*1000000

dat
  revenue  revenue2
1 $121.5M 121500000
2 $0.014M     14000
```